# Reading file error: File Not Found

Tags: java

I have the follwing

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("hello.txt"));
   while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
       int i = scanner.nextInt();
       System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Why do I get an error when I run it? It says `file not found (The system cannot find the files specificed)` in `java.io.fileinputstream`. But the file does exist.

Comment: Perhaps your working directory isn't where you think it is?

Comment: Where is your `hello.txt` file found? What's the path to it? Is it relative to some well-known location? (The user's home directory, the current path, the working directory when the program is invoked...)

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify an **absolute** path. Right now you're specifying a *relative* path. The path is relative to the current working directory over which you have no control from inside the Java code. The relative path depends on how you're executing the Java code. In command prompt, it's the currently opened folder. In an IDE like Eclipse, it's the project's root folder. In a webapplication, it's the Server's binary folder, etc.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/full/path/to/hello.txt"));
```

In a Windows environment, the above example equals to `C:\full\path\to\hello.txt`.

---

If your *actual* intent is to place this file in the same folder of the currently running class, then you should be obtaining it as a classpath resource:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(getClass().getResouceAsStream("hello.txt"));
```

Or if you're inside the `static` context:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(YourClass.class.getResouceAsStream("hello.txt"));
```

Where `YourClass` is the class in question.

Comment: *"You need to specify an absolute path"* Not necessarily. If the program is run from the directory in which the file is located, it works. Daniel's comment is more on-point, I think: If you're going to use a relative path, ensure that you're in the right place.

Comment: @T.J You don't want to be dependent on the environment like that. You would risk portability problems. Obtaining as a classpath resource is the safest way since you can control it from inside your application.

Comment: so I should write "/User/hello.txt"

Comment: @Bob: if you have a folder named `User` on the root with therein the `hello.txt`, then yes. As long as it complies the local disk file system.

Comment: I tried "/User/hello.txt" and it didn't work I'm using BlueJ and but the file in the same place my class is written in I'm still stuck unfortunatly

Comment: @BalusC: You still don't *need* to. It may be *best*, depending on the problem you're solving -- or not, depending on the problem you're solving. (Absolute paths are a bad portability idea; relative to a classpath is better.) For instance, when dealing with a user-entered filename, they're not going to be interested in requiring that it be a full path. Regardless, saying you *need* to is misleading.

Comment: @Bob: Then it simply doesn't exist on the local disk file system (i.e. there's nothing on `C:\User\hello.txt`). Verify the path. I however recommend to obtain it as classpath resource instead. @T.J if it's supposed to be enduser's input, I'd document it properly in the manual/help where s/he is supposed to place the file, or just spawn a `JFileChooser` so that you at least get a `File` with the correct absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, you could solve the problem by specifying an absolute path.  However, you actually DO have some control over the current working directory from within the Java code.  If the file you're reading is in the current working directory, then you could use this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(
    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separatorChar +"hello.txt"));
```

The "user.dir" system level property contains the directory from which your application is running.  Note that this ISN'T necessarily the directory in which the ".class" file resides.  If that's what you're wanting, then the best approach would be loading it as a classpath resource (well covered in another answer.)

Comment: This doesn't change things :) The `File` already defaults to the current working directory when a relative path is given. Check the javadoc of e.g. `getAbsolutePath()` method.

Comment: It still says file not found! I am so confused This should be very simple!

Comment: @BalusC: Quite! Steve, perhaps you meant `System.getProperty("user.home")`.